# What is this cable called?

Tags: identification, cables

What is this cable called?
I need to extend it with a male to female cable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a connector.  It would help if we could also see the cable to see if it's stranded IDC etc.

Comment: Look at my edit...

Comment: it could be this: http://pinoutsguide.com/Power/apple_mac_pro_psuj3_pinout.shtml (the 12 pin Mac Pro PSU J3)

Comment: It is a custom connector, the easiest solution is to use 0.1" male pin header and plastic goo (e.g. sugru) to make a counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

As @Venny has said, it looks to be a custom connector. It looks like a press fit, non-latching, 0.1" header for external use. If you measure it out to confirm, you could make your own using 6x2 male and female Headers, or a 6x2 idc cable with a set of 6x2 male 0.1" header placed in one end as an adapter.

It may not fit in the male receptor, so you may think about cutting and splicing a longer cable in the middle.